# Solving DDE with small time steps in for loop

Tags: matlab, delay, ode, dde

I want to solve following DDE using a for loop in MATLAB:

```
xdot(t) = Ax(t) + BKx(t-h)
```

in which:

```
A = [0 1 ; -1 0.1];
B = [0 ; 1];
h = 0.2;
K = [-0.0469 -1.7663];
t = [0 5]
```

Solving this with conventional procedure is simple and the results are acceptable.

```
sol = dde23(ddefun,lags,history,tspan,options,varargin)
```

However, when I try to solve it using for loop, the results are wrong. Here is a simple code for my for loop.

```
time = 0:0.001:5;
for i = 2:5001
x(:,1) = [1 -1];
history(:,1) = [1 -1];
[t h] = ode23(@(t,h)histExam1(t,h,A,B,K),[time(i-1)    time(i)],history(:,i-1));
history(:,i)= h(end,:);
sol = dde23(((@(t,y,z)ddefun(t,y,z,A,B,K))),0.2,history(:,i),[time(i-1) time(i)]);
x(:,i)=sol.y(:,end);
end
```

I think, the only problem in this code is my time steps and delay input. I use same dde function for both codes so It cannot be a problem.The reason I want to solve DDE in a for loop is "BK" value which is state dependent (not in this simple example) and in each time step I need to update "BK".
[image]

The correct answer plotted above with conventional method.
[image]
And the wrong answer I get using "for loop" is plotted above.
It is interesting to mention that correct answer is sensitive to delay. But delay doesn’t affect the answer from 2nd method.

Comment: Your time spans from 0 to 5 in the first sectio: tspan = [0 5], but then in your loop it starts at [0.001 to 0.002]...Is that what you want? It also looks like you have two inputs for your lags, 0 and 02, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the loop is between 0.001 to 0,002 and delay is 0.02. is it pissible to model the equation like this?
No, I have only one time delay. BKx(t-h) where h=0.02.

Comment: Ok, so first just make sure that the 0,02 is actually 0.02 in your code. And then go through a couple loops and print out what you get vs. what you should get so we can see the type of problem you're experiencing.

Comment: What do you mean by this: "make sure that the 0,02 is actually 0.02 in your code"
I just put 0.02 in lags. should it be something else?

Comment: In the code you posted above, it is a comma and not a decimal. So if you copied and pasted your code, then it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the delay value. it was a typo mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After weeks of thinking, finally found a solution.
Simply:

```
sol = dde23(((@(t,y,z)ddefun(t,y,z,A,B,K))),0.2,[1;-1],[0 time(i)]);
```

and let the magics happen.
This code helps you with updating states at each time step.
I hope it will help you in the future.

All the Best,

Sina

Comment: could you please add your full code here? I have same problem and want to use your code as a working example